# Removing files and symlinks like /etc/*release. Could it cause issues?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

I just got a VM running on CentOS 6.5 and `ls -l /etc/*release` returns a number of files like `/etc/centos-release`, `/etc/lsb-release`, and `/etc/redhat-release`.

The last one, `/etc/redhat-release`, is a symlink to the centos-release file.

Is it safe to remove `/etc/redhat-release`?
Or could it cause issues later?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62709/which-of-these-three-commands-is-telling-the-true-redhat-release-information

Comment: Why do you want to remove `/etc/redhat-release`?

Comment: @Faheem 
I'm asking out of curiosity. Trying to figure out how important /etc/*release files are.

Comment: @cpugeniusmv 
Thanks for the link. That is definitely handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that some third-party software could check for the existence/contents of that file and do something variable based on the result. So, for example, if something is designed to run *only* on RHEL and not CentOS, checking that file would be a simple (and FWIW, easy to bypass) way to enforce that.

I would be surprised if there is a good reason for removing these files.

Comment: Is this a standard way to check for OS level though?
Wouldn't it make more sense to look at `lsb_release -d` for instance?

Comment: I don't appear to have `lsb_release` installed on my CentOS 6.4 box. Looks like there are some `redhat-lsb-*` packages that I don't have installed. This must have been a really lean install (and not likely fully lsb-compliant!).

The existence of that file makes a quick test in shell scripts possible: `[ -e /etc/redhat-release ] && echo redhat`

Comment: Also consider that it's possible that `lsb_release` may even reference that file for some reason.